# Looking for a full AJAX cms

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flash, content-management-system

Is-there any CMS to generate a full ajax website (in order to show a persistant flash component without reloading it at each page browsing)

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea.  AJAX has its place, but over-use is a bad idea as well.  Look into CMS' everyone else is using and see if those work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This might be one of those few situations where frames can be a solution.

use an Iframe for the mainh site and have the flash in the outer page, that way the flash will never reload while the site in the ifram does.

I agree with the comment, a pure Ajax site is a monster to handle (have tried) and I doubt there are any CMS that generate pure ajax sites.

Answer (score 1):

I know Plone has been used for something similar to this for at least the previous version of http://www.wolford.com/ but with rather major customisations.

The CMS was used to handle the flash files, the images, texts etc — then to output XML for the Flash appllication to consume instead of HTML for the browser.

That said, i wouldn't recommend such a solution. AJAX-only websites have too many drawbacks to be of much good.